# Positioning Elements, DIV's and IMG's

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this project I'm doing for practice. I'm having trouble with the innovation cloud project. Please explain me how to fix this.

1. I can't manage to get the "Learn More" button to be below the paragraph in the header section.
2. I can't manage to get the image in the main section to float left of the Header and paragraph.
3. I also can't manage the jumbotron DIV to appear below main. The image fuses with main, it doesn't appear below it where it should be.

Here is the pen for a visual: http://codepen.io/alejoj/pen/xGBbwv

Thanks for your help.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 940px; 
 padding: 0 10px; 
}


/* Header */
.header {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/innovation-cloud/bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.header .container {
 position: relative;
 top: 200px;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size: 80px;
 line-height: 100px; 
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

@media (min-width:850px) {
 .header h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
 }
}

.header p {
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 margin-top: 0;
  color: white;
}
.btn{
 width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
 margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
 background: #117bff;
 cursor: pointer; 
 transition: background .5s;
}


/* Nav */
.nav{
 background-color: black;
}
.nav ul {
  display: table;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 padding: 30px 0;
 text-align: center; 
}
.nav li{
  display: cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* Main */
.main .container {
 margin: 80px auto;
}
.main h2, p{
 display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.main img{
 height: 150px;
 width: 35%%;
  margin: 50px -5px 50px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
/* Jumbotron */
.jumbotron {
  margin: 10px 0;
 height: 600px; 
 text-align: right;
  background-image:url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/innovation-cloud/jumbotron_bg.jpg');
}

.jumbotron .container {
 position: relative;
 top: 220px;
}


/* Footer */
.footer { 
 font-size: 14px;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 64px;
  }
  .clearfix{
   clear: both;
  }
  .main, .jumbotron {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }

  .main img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1> INNOVATION CLOUD </h1>
        <p>CONNECT YOUR IDEAS GLOBALLY</p>
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Learn More">
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li>Register</li>
          <li>Schedule</li>
          <li>Sponsors</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
                <img id="mainImage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/innovation-cloud/cloud.svg" />

        <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
        <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions to challenging problems.</p>
        <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most challenging projects.</p>
         <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clreafix"></div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about your desired outcome, but it seems that this css was throwing off a lot of what you want to fix:

```
.main h2, p {
   display: inline-block; 
   float: left;
}
```

If you remove that and change the right margin on your image from -5 to 50 it looks pretty good like this:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNbyEP

Floating elements can really throw off your layout if you don't "clear" the floats.  Sometimes I add a br style="clear:both"  after floated elements to keep the flow looking as expected (in the case of not seeing your jumbotron image where it should be)

Answer (score -1):

1. You have your `p` set to `inline-block`. Remove this:

   `.main h2, p {
      display: inline-block; 
      float: left;
   }`
2. You have negative right margin on your image. Change this:

   `margin: 50px -5px 50px 0px;`

   to:

   `margin: 50px 50px 50px 0px;`
3. Not sure what you mean.